# Python how to compare data like in PHP arrays

Tags: php, python

I have to compare different operations results on two data sources using Python.

For each datasource, I get all tables names. For each table, I get all columns. For each column, I do some 'operations' like getting count(column), sum(column). For example, in PHP, it would have given this type of array:

```
----------------------------------------------------
[TABLE1][COL1][OPERATION1][value]
[TABLE1][COL1][OPERATION2][value]
[TABLE1][COL1][OPERATION3][value]
----------------------------------------------------
[TABLE1][COL2][OPERATION1][value]
[TABLE1][COL2][OPERATION2][value]
[TABLE1][COL2][OPERATION3][value]
----------------------------------------------------
[TABLE2][COL1][OPERATION1][value]
[TABLE2][COL1][OPERATION2][value]
[TABLE2][COL1][OPERATION3][value]
----------------------------------------------------
[TABLE2][COL2][OPERATION1][value]   
[TABLE2][COL2][OPERATION2][value]
[TABLE2][COL2][OPERATION3][value]
----------------------------------------------------
```

I need to compare the results of the operations between the two data sources, it means verify if all tables and columns exist on each one, and compare the result of the 'operation'. I have tried to find a way how to realise this using objects but I don't know how. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You should rephrase your question into something concrete. What exactly do you want to compare?

Comment: I have added explanations, hope it's clear now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if the results are the same, use `==`. For example

```
dict1 = {'foo':'bar'}
dict2 = {'foo':'baz'}

dict1 == dict2
# False

dict2 = {'foo':'bar'}

dict1 == dict2
# True
```